# what to consider before creating index?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT OEH.HEADER_ID, OEH.ORDER_NUMBER
                ,oel.line_number
                ,oel.pricing_quantity_uom as UOM
                ,oel.attribute1 as customer_length
                ,oel.attribute6 as theoretical_weight
FROM OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL OEH JOIN
     OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL OEL
     ON OEH.ORG_ID = OEL.ORG_ID AND
        OEH.HEADER_ID = OEL.HEADER_ID
WHERE OEL.LINK_TO_LINE_ID IS NULL;
```

I am facing Nested loops and want to tune this query, on what columns I need to create an index?

Comment: Showing the execution plan, table structures and current indexes in your question would help. Why do you think you need an index at all?

Comment: @AlexPoole these are oracle OM tables, just I want what columns I need to consider for indexes, I have a very long query, that will not be so good to post here. Just want an idea what columns need to be consider for indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient rule is to index the columns used in the `JOIN`s:  `OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL(ORG_ID, HEADER_ID)` and `OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL(ORG_ID, HEADER_ID)`.

In fact, Oracle will probably use only one of these for the `JOIN`, but it will choose the better one.

Comment: do I need to include the columns which are in select clause?

Comment: That can make the query marginally faster.  But, because you are likely reading the entire table anyway, the table will be loaded into the page cache and it might not make much difference (in general).